# Equivalence of topological and complex analytic definitions of degree of a line bundle.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Let $\Sigma$ be a compact Riemann surface. Let $\mathcal{O},\mathcal{O}^*, \mathbb{Z}$ be, respectively, the sheaves of holomorphic functions, nonvanishing holomorphic functions, and integer-valued locally constant functions on $\Sigma$. Pointwise addition makes $\mathbb{Z},\mathcal{O}$ sheaves of abelian groups. Pointwise multiplication makes $\mathcal{O}^*$ a sheaf of abelian groups.

Consider the short exact sequence 
$$0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}\rightarrow \mathcal{O}^* \rightarrow 0,$$
where the first map is the inclusion and the second is $f\mapsto \exp{(2\pi i f)}$. As part of the associated long exact sequence, we get a connecting homomorphism
$$ H^1(\mathcal{O}^*)\rightarrow H^2(\mathbb{Z}).$$
We identify $H^1(\mathcal{O}^*)$ with the group of isomorphism classes of holomorphic line bundles on $\Sigma$. (Use a Čech cocycle representing an element of $H^1(\mathcal{O}^*)$ as transition data for a line bundle.)

How do you prove that the image of a line bundle under the boundary map is the same as the topologically defined Euler class of the bundle?

Comment: Just to be absolutely clear, what definition of Euler class are you using?

Comment: Any purely topological definition, say, the Poincare dual of the intersection of a generic smooth section with the zero section.

Comment: Or the pullback of the first Chern class of the universal bundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized this question was discussed in the comments for this question: [Algebraic versus topological line bundles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14826/algebraic-versus-topological-line-bundles?rq=1)
As pointed out there, there's a proof using Chern-Weil theory in Chapter III, Section 4 of Differential Analysis on Complex Manifolds, by Wells.

Comment: In particular, you want Theorem $4.5$.